# Custom package is not in golang std

Tags: go

Trying to run my golang code and it exits with this error:

`main.go:5:2: package lesson/students is not in std (C:\Program Files\Go\src\lesson\students)`

Can't find info in google, help me please(

**Project structure**

```
project/
    lesson/
        students.go
    main.go
    go.mod
```

**main.go**

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "lesson/students"
)

func main() {
    student1 := students.Student{}
    fmt.Println(student1)
}
```

**lesson/students.go**

```
package students

type Student struct {
    Name string
    age  int
}
```

go.mod created by `go mod init lesson`

Comment: The main problem was in lesson/ folder which is extra, i just had to made students/ folder in my project root. Then it works great. @Volker, thx for explaining, but as I mentioned, i did NOT find info in https://go.dev/doc/code.

Comment: Read and follow the "Tutorial"s in https://go.dev/doc/.

Comment: @DJsega1 I tried fiddling with folder structure, and it doesn't resolve it for me. Do you have any concrete explanation or solution for this problem. The go document seems to vague.

Answer (score 3):

in your `project/go.mod` you can find something like

```
module project

go 1.XX.X
```

this mod file knows the path to the dependencies being called by the `main.go`, taking from the name you gave to the package `project` and pointing to the current directory onwards. You could say it sets the working dir of the package, and the scope of declared stuff is given by the subfolders structure.

Lets say you want to use the `Students` struct in the `main.go` you would need to import `project/lesson` then access it through `lesson.Student({...})`, it doesn't matter if the `Student` is in the `project/lesson/students.go` file or the `project/lesson/anything.go` file

```golang
package project

import (
    "fmt"

    "project/lesson"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(lesson.Student{Name: "John", Age: 25}) //will show {John 25}
}
```

btw `Student.age` should be `Student.Age` for it to be visible, also the `student.go` file should start with the `package lesson` statement

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to check your root module path. My root module path in my go.mod file

- was `module project/module/sub-module`,
- changing it to `module project/module`
  meant go could locate the files in the sub-modules and run the program.

In my case my file `go.mod` had this reference `module example.com/mymod` like this

```golang
module example.com/mymod

go 1.21.1
```

after changing it to only `module mymod` like this

```golang
module mymod

go 1.21.1
```

the error `package mymod/foo is not in std` was fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I got this error because I was running `go run filename` with no file extension, I needed to run `go run filename.go`

Answer (score 0):

run :: go work use  .

On your project directory.

Answer (score -1):

`project/lesson/students` folder is extra, i just had to made `project/students/` folder. Then it works great without any changes.

Comment: What do you mean?  Can you please share the before and after?

Answer (score -1):

You should install your custom module:

```
go install project/lesson/students.go
```