# package "PracticeSimpleCode/grettings" is not in std (/usr/local/go/src/PractiseSimpleCode/grettings)

Tags: go

my source codes are in /home/user/go/src/PracticeSimpleCode. under PracticeSimpleCode their are many subdirectory which has its own .go file. Now i have created a local package named grettings. when i call it from hi, after running by go run hi.go it shows me this error <hi.go:4:2: package PracticeSimpleCode/grettings is not in std (/usr/local/go/src/PracticeSimpleCode/grettings)>. and i doent have go.mod and go.sum. but other program without importing custom package works fine.

grettings.go

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6iCrC.png)

hi.go

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tfgIN.png)

i tried google  but i didnt find something that much useful.[Custom package is not in golang std](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77162842/custom-package-is-not-in-golang-std) this is somehow related to this but i dont know what exatcly i should do.

Comment: The long and short of this is you need a `go.mod` file, which defines `module PracticeSimpleCode`, otherwise it will not be able to locate things within the `module`, such as sub-packages.

Comment: which go version you are using?

Comment: i am using go1.21.5

Comment: and when i have created a go.mod file in PracticeSimpleCode it is also showing a problem " could not import PractiseSimpleCode/grettings (cannot find package "PractiseSimpleCode/grettings" in GOROOT or GOPATH)compilerBrokenImport " and when i run it it says the same thing that it is not in std

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.